# How to fix 'ffmpeg server returned 403 forbidden (access denied)?

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, youtube, converters

I'm writing a website to convert youtube videos using NodeJS. I am using a package to convert them (horizon-youtube-mp3). The package works, however, I'm having problems converting. Whenever I try to convert a youtube link, it will return 'server returned 403 forbidden access'. 
This error happens in 95% of the links. Some links actually work and convert correctly, but only a few.

I tried running the script on 3 different computers running 3 different OS's. My VPS, my laptop and my home PC. I looked on the web but couldn't find anything useful.

So yeah, I completely suck since I really don't understand why one video would convert, and the other won't. Even if the region of the video is the same.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: It’s probably YouTube that is returning a 403 response.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is there a way to get around this though?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get new link. I just had the same mistake. I copied a new link to the same file (*they were different when I compared them*) and everything worked.